# How to change the primary color?

Tags: css, angular, sass, materialize

I am using **angular2-material** and would like to change the primary color of Materialize CSS. In ***node_modules\materialize-css\sass\components_variables.scss***

I have found this code:

```
// 1. Colors
// ==========================================================================

$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !default;

$secondary-color: color("teal", "lighten-1") !default;
$success-color: color("green", "base") !default;
$error-color: color("red", "base") !default;
$link-color: color("light-blue", "darken-1") !default;
```

But when I change the colors, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you changing the color? Go through this https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: @Yousefkhan instead of `red`, I just typed `blue`. By the way, I am using Materialized CSS (materializecss.com). Is this the same as Angular Material?

Comment: @RezaSaadati are you compiling the Sass files in some way?

Comment: @RachGlucio no, I thought they would be compiled, if I use `ng serve`?!

Comment: @RezaSaadati 
I do not really know how to do your project, but if your styles do not compile again when doing a rebuild, then you could add sass/scss and webpack to create a new style sheet and write the variables